# Send multiple collections to one ejs file using mongodb and nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, collections, ejs

```
app.get('/index', function(req, res){            
    Activities.find({}, function(err, activity){
      if(err){
          console.log(err);
      }else{
          res.render('index', {activities:activity});
      }
    });
    Upcoming.find({}, function(err, upcomingActivity){
      if(err){
          console.log(err);
      }else{
          res.render('index', {upcoming:upcomingActivity});
      }
    });
});
```

I just want to get data of multiple collections and then pass it to index.ejs file so that i can use these data there.
I know using res.render() multiple times won't work but i have tried many things like saving founded data to variable , creating an object of these etc. But nothing
worked.

Comment: first make a single object using the two result set and send that object with your view.I hope that will solve the issue

Answer (score 0):

In your get response you should render only once the index page passing the parameters all together.

```
    app.get('/index', function(req, res){            
        Activities.find({}, function(err, activity){
          if(err){
              console.log(err);
          }else{
                  Upcoming.find({}, function(err, upcomingActivity){
          if(err){
              console.log(err);
          }else{
              res.render('index', {activity:activity, upcoming:upcomingActivity,});
          }
        });
          }
        });
    });
```

It will work this way, since you have only a few collections but other way to do so is passing it as a global object and then rendering it.

Answer (score 0):

Use `then` to render asynchronously

```
app.get('/index', (req,res) => {
    Activities.find().then(activity => {
            Upcoming.find().then(upcomingActivity => {
                res.render('index', {Activities: activity, Upcoming: upcomingActivity})
            }).catch(err => console.log(err))
}).catch(err => console.log(err))
})
```